# Frankfurt airport transit time and procedure with My Cloud hotel

Tags: layovers, fra

I am arriving on a Condor flight from Canada to Frankfurt (FRA) airport (per Google, this arrived to B43) and want to continue to on a Lufthansa flight within the Schengen area (somehow this is also a B gate). I will have hand luggage only. I also have an electronic passport issued by a Schengen country.

I intend to stay at the My Cloud hotel which says

> Only passengers with an arriving or departing non-Schengen flight have access.

So far so good. I have some questions on how this will actually work:

1. When do I need to do border checks and how many? (before/after hotel)
2. Will I need to pass security? (before/after hotel)
3. What does my timeline look like, 3a) from the arriving to the hotel 3b) from the hotel to the gate?

Comment: Do you mean your connecting flight is the following day?  In that case, does it actually matter for the purpose of the question that you have a connecting flight?

Answer (score 2):

The hotel got back me with a partial answer

> Our hotel are situated in Z area , if you will land in B the way to us will take around 30-45 minutes, and you will pass through security control, and back will be the same way and one more security control.

After this I didn't bother asking whether I need to pass immigration control as this makes the in-terminal hotel a completely pointless very expensive option. A day use of the Sheraton costs *half*. And while the signs at Frankfurt are not at all helpful in finding the footpath to the hotels, if you know -- and now you do -- to follow the signs to the *train station* and when you reach the overpass for that, then you will find the signs finally:

[image]

I have not seen hotel signs elsewhere.

There's a [source](https://cepr.org/sites/default/files/3564_Travel%20from%20and%20to%20Frankfurt%20Airport.pdf) which says

> From the long-distance train station to Terminal 1: Walk across the pedestrian bridge and follow the signs to Terminal 1 A/B/C/Z, total walking time: approx. 10 minutes

so the distance from the terminals to the Sheraton is just ten minutes -- and you only need to pass security once, on the way from the hotel to your gate.

Answer (score 1):

As the rules state that only passengers with a non-Schengen flight have access, I work out that your hotel will be airside, in the 'non-Schengen' part of the airport.
From that you can expect not to pass through passport control (nor security) between the arriving flight and the hotel.
This does mean that you will have a very short time between getting off your flight and getting to your hotel. But it also means that you can not pick up any luggage which is checked only to this airport. So your plan of carry-on luggage only will work.

After your stay in the hotel you will pass through immigration, customs is very much likely to be at your final destination.
It is not impossible that you will have to pass through security (after passport control, on the way to your flight,) but I am not familiar with the airport and not all have that for all originating airports.
As you will be a passenger who is transfering from outside to inside Schengen, it is rather likely that your queues will be short, but many airports in many parts of Europe struggle with a lack of workers, so best check (or ask at the hotel) what to expect.

Note, I am not familiar with the airport nor the hotel, I go by what they wrote in the 'rules'.